# set default url param if not exist .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm a bit stuck on how to solve this.

The edge case I'm testing for is if someone goes to the URL but removes the query params.

**EXAMPLE**

```
www.example.com
```

I want to be able to check if there are no URL params given then set it to a default and redirect with the default URL params.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
www.example.com?year=2016
```

This is my code I'm using or misusing. Some help would be very much appreciated.

```
Dim noURLParam As String = ""
If Not(Request.QueryString("Year") Is Nothing) Then
  If Request.QueryString("Year").ToString() <> "" Then
    noURLParam = Request.QueryString("Year").ToString()
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Why aren't you just setting whatever the default you want to `noURLParam`?

Comment: wasn't aware you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is currently structured you can simply do this

```
' Set a default
Dim noURLParam As String = "2017"
```

And `2017` will be the default if no value is provided for `year` in the querystring.

Comment: We are really scraping the bottom of the barrel here with some of these vb.net questions.